# SQL Azure : Executing SQL directly; no cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, vb6, azure-sql-database

I'm developing an app in vb6 and I'm trying to do queries on `SQL AZURE` thanks to the `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` but each time I execute a query (even a simple `select * from Users;`) the Native Client returned this error :

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server] Executing SQL directly; no cursor.
```

This problem occurs since I have created a new DB with a different level on azure portal. The database before was a `web` DB and the new one is a `Standard` DB. Is there a manip to do for the three new versions of DB in `Azure(Basic,Standard,Premium)` ?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Changing editions shouldn't cause this issue. Looks like there is some problem with your application. Did you try searching online, I see multiple solutions. Please try those.

Comment: By switching the new DB with the old one it's working. And if I switch to the new one, this error occurs.

Comment: could you paste the code  please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error in question is 16954 (your error reporting should first and foremost show the error number, state and severity, not only the error message). It occurs when an application attempts to use server side cursors in a context not supported. See [Client-Side Cursors Versus Server-Side Cursors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266531(v=vs.60).aspx). This is likely coming from your cursor library choice in RDO, see [Choosing an RDO Cursor Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240805(v=vs.60).aspx). Switch to `rdUseIfNeeded` or `rdUseNone`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in the process of switching from `Web` to `Standard` you also switched to a [Azure SQL V12 DB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-v12-whats-new/) which is a very different technology from previous versions. I'm not aware of ODBC/RDO incompatibilities in V12, but RDO is a  *very* old technology.

Comment: indeed, I just see the version of the SQL Azure is "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8"

Comment: Azure gets pretty clunky.  You have to front-end it with client side cursors and to use ADO you thunk through MSDASQL into a creaky ODBC driver because Microsoft is deprecating OLEDB to enhance portability as they try to support non-Windows platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the underlying error is getting hidden by the sql client.
If you are getting an error for simple `select * from table` queries then I would check you have permissions for the credentials your app is using.

Comment: By using php with the same user and password, it's working. And when I'm connect to the db with db forge studio express its working too.